# Rails asset pipeline can't find one certain image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a certain image called `ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png`. In production it can be found, among other places, in `public/assets/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png`.

When I try to view this image in production, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png"):
```

I find this extremely odd since the image most certainly is there:

```
$ find . -name ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
./vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery-ui/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
./public/assets/jquery-ui/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
./public/assets/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
```

All the other images in my app work fine and have been forever. I recently upgraded my version of jQuery UI, though, and this one particular image doesn't want to work. (I think it's the only jQuery UI image I'm actually using.)

I'm on Rails 3.2.1. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your js plugin requests the image with invalid asset url.
The asset image can be accessed by

```
/assets/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
```

But the requested url is

```
/assets/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
```

So in your javascript or stylesheet you need to correct asset url manually.

Comment: I don't know if that's it. I can navigate just fine to, say, `http://sniphq.com/assets/images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100-951e2a65945b93d3f69c1994e5672f39.png`, but I can't navigate to `http://sniphq.com/assets/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png`. So even outside of the JS or stylesheet, there's a problem.

Comment: Okay, you were right after all. If I change the path from `/assets/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png` to `/assets/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png`, it works. I don't want to manually change this path for everything to do with jQuery UI, though. I wonder what to do about that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798646/what-are-the-best-practices-when-organizing-assets-in-rails-asset-pipeline -- This may be the solution you need. Change the asset path to search in additional locations