# rails 4.0 routing error for image using jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, routes, raty

I'm using a star rating jquery plugin that requires a few star images in my rails 4 application. The images aren't showing up and I keep getting an error saying

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/star-on.png"):

similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182696/rails-asset-pipeline-cant-find-one-certain-image) issue and I tried to move the location of my images but it didn't work, still got the same error. they're currently in app/assets/javascripts/images but I moved them into the root directory and it didn't fix the issue. I also tried editing the javascript to change the path of the images but that didn't work either. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7336734/2739431) but it didn't work as well. Any help on this would be really appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/star-on.png")** error was raised your image had to be in **root/public** directory to prevent this error. In general, your images should be in **root/app/assets/images** or in **root/vendor/assets/images** directory. I don't know what image paths are in the jquery plugin, therefore I can't answer your question. Maybe locating images in the same folder where .js files are located will also solve the problem.

Comment: Assets are rendered as /assets/xxxx.js or css or png. So here the image should be in ./public folder